# How to change Browser button name?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

As I am new in UI development ,Kindly help to provide solution. How to change the Browser button name by using jquery.

Comment: `$('.classname').text('newname')` demo here -->https://jsfiddle.net/kajtcppj/

Comment: `$('#buttonId').val('newButtonname')` if using `<input type="submit" ... />`
`$('#buttonId').attr('value','newButtonname')` also if using input or `<button type="submit ... ></button>"`
`$('#buttonId').text('newButtonname')` if using a simple `<button></button>` or `<a href="">...</a>`

Comment: What is a "Browser button"?

Comment: what do you mean by browser button?

Answer (score 1):

That would be `$('selector').text('some other name')`

If your element is an `<input>`, then you can use `$('selector').val('some other name')`